# Why adding a club of $\aleph_1$ collapses $\aleph_1$ to $\aleph_0$?

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Let $\{S_n \mid n < \omega\}$ be a partition of $\aleph_1$ into countably many disjoint stationary subsets. Why adding a club of $\aleph_1$ to each  $\aleph_1 \setminus S_n$ collapses $\aleph_1$ to $\aleph_0$?

Would it collapse $\aleph_1$ also adding single element to   $\aleph_1 \setminus S_n$ for each $n < \omega$?

Or adding unbounded set for each $n$, not necessarily closed?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** You add countably many clubs, suppose you didn't collapse $\aleph_1$, the intersection of all these clubs is still a club $A$. What do you know about $A\cap S_n$ and about the *countable* union $\bigcup(A\cap S_n)$?

---

For your second question, the answer is that you can do that without collapsing $\aleph_1$. Namely, given $S\subseteq\omega_1$ such that $\omega_1\setminus S$ is stationary, you can add a club which is disjoint from $S$ without collapsing $\aleph_1$. You can do that simply by looking at countable closed subsets which are disjoint of $S$, ordered by end-extension.

For the third question, you can just add any new subset of $\omega_1$, even one induced by adding a real, and look at how it translates to subsets of each $\omega_1\setminus S_n$.

Comment: Both $A\cap S_n$ and the *countable* union $\bigcup(A\cap S_n)$ will be empty, is it a contradiction with what?

Comment: We can use De Morgan Law to get $\bigcup(A\cap S_n)=A \cap \bigcup S_n$ which is nonempty;so why we need *countable* here?

Comment: You need to use the fact that the countable union of non-stationary sets is non stationary. Now, as in your second comment, what is $\bigcup S_n$? Do you see the contradiction?

Comment: Yes,I can see where is the contradiction,but I don't know why the countable union of non-stationary sets is non stationary.Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Do you know that the intersection of countably many clubs is a club?

Comment: Sorry,only intuitively, I have no proof of this.But let's say that the intersection of two clubs is a club,that's what I can see.

Comment: Well, just prove that it's a club. It's not very hard.

Comment: Ok,I have an argument.What next?

Comment: Finish the proof...

Comment: I am more than certain that the downvote wasn't personal, but rather because the answer was only partial. So whoever did that, instead of bothering to write an answer of their own can sleep quietly at night, knowing that I've added answers to the other side questions. And thank you for reminding me, and also for taking the time to read my answer and the comments, which I am sure that you did before voting!

Comment: I don't see how the answer is partial. In fact, I think you could have stopped after the first sentence.

Comment: @hot_queen: I don't either. But to be fair, the OP did ask about adding clubs disjoint from one stationary set, and just adding unbounded sets. So in that sense the answer was incomplete.